# How to design a data logger?

Tags: homework, instrumentation, datalogger, data-acquisition

[image: image showing solution attempt so far]

> Signals from three transducers are to be recorded in data logger. The analogue signal supplied by the three transducers are dual polarity (-50 mV to +50 mV) having frequency is 5 kHz, 10 kHz and 15 kHz. Explain the design of the following steps of the data logger.
>
> 1. Input scanner off the data logger such that it can appropriately sample the incoming signals.
> 2. Signal conditioner of stages if the 8-bit ADC used inside the data logger accepts only positive polarity signals ranging from 0 volt to 5 volts.

What I have tried is shown in image above.

In the image, I have taken 3 signals and a multiplexer switch. That is how I have designed the input scanner. Plus sampling rate would have to be 2*15KHz.

I am stuck in part 2. How do I solve this part? It says data logger accepts only positive polarity signals  from 0 to 5 Volts. It also gives transducers voltage as -50mV to +50 mV. How do I use this information to solve the second question?

Here what I have tried is that voltage swing is 0.1V, whereas gain=5/0.1=50

So, required voltage = 50 * 50mV = 2.5V.

But I am not very clear about this.

Comment: Team B.I - Hi, I know you said (in a now-deleted comment) that this was an exam question, not homework. However for any of that type of question, we need to see your best solution attempt & you must ask a *clear* question showing exactly where you are stuck. (a) That solution attempt is very unclear. You have drawn a diagram, but not explained anything about it; and (b) You haven't asked a specific question. Therefore this question is now "on hold" waiting for you to [Edit] the question, explain where you are stuck & ask a specific question. Then the question will be considered for re-opening.

Comment: Are you asking how to turn a +/-50 mV signal to a 0-5v signal?  Did you class go over opamps?  The normal way to do this would be to use an amplifier to apply gain and a DC offset.

Comment: I was absent in those classes due to sickness. Can you recommend what topics should I study in order to get those basics? @user1850479

Comment: @TeamB.I - Thank you for adding details about where you are stuck. I have re-opened the question. As *user1850479* has mentioned, there are relevant topics which you can research yourself (either on the internet or on this site) to help with the required signal conditioning.

Comment: I am planning to watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xaOF2SNktRY. Can you recommend some good resources that I can follow to learn this topic? @SamGibson?